# $a^{x} - b^{x}$ expansion

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

We know that  $a^n - b^n = (a-b)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}b + \cdots  + ab^{n-2} + b^{n-1})$ for $ n \in \mathbb{N}.$ Is it possible to give some expansion formula when $a,b$ both are positive and $x$ is some real number such that $x \geq 1$ or can we estimate $a^x - b ^x$ by $|a-b|^x$ ?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "expansion formula". On the other hand, for every $a,b>0$ and $n\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists $c\in[a,b]$ such that $a^n-b^n=(a-b)nc^{n-1}$. In particular, $|a^n-b^n|\leq n|a-b|\max(a^{n-1},b^{n-1})$. See Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: If there were a desired *expansion*, what would be the gain? A good answer could help to define a sensible notion of *expansion*.

Comment: Thanks, I got it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an expansion, but it is infinite.
To simplify, set $x=a/b$, $f(x)=x^n-1$. This is an analytic function
on the positive ray, so it has a Taylor expansion at $x=1$:
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{n(n-1)\ldots(n-k+1)}{k!}(x-1)^k.$$
And to answer your second question, yes, $f(x)$ can be estimated in terms
of $x-1$, since the series begins with the first power.